# Matrix Multiplication "*" works in MATLAB but not in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a `5 x 3` matrix `X` by its transpose `tX` in R.

```
> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   13  0.5
[2,]    1   23  0.4
[3,]    1    7 -0.2
[4,]    1   16  1.0
[5,]    1   11  0.3

> tX
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.0  1.0  1.0    1  1.0
[2,] 13.0 23.0  7.0   16 11.0
[3,]  0.5  0.4 -0.2    1  0.3

> tX * X
Error in tX * X: array incompatibili
```

I did this in MATLAB and got immediately the right result. Why can't I do this in R? Thank You.

[compute this in MATLAB](http://www.calcul.com/show/calculator/matrix-multiplication_;5;3;3;5?matrix1=[[%221%22,%221%22,%221%22,%221%22,%221%22],[%2213%22,%2223%22,%227%22,%2216%22,%2211%22],[%220.5%22,%220.4%22,%22-0.2%22,%221%22,%220.3%22]]&matrix2=[[%221%22,%2213%22,%220.5%22],[%221%22,%2223%22,%220.4%22],[%221%22,%227%22,%22-0.2%22],[%221%22,%2216%22,%221%22],[%221%22,%2211%22,%220.3%22]]&operator=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `tX %*% X`. Or try `crossprod(X)`. See `?"%*%"`.

Actually, if you just read the [matrix-multiplication](/questions/tagged/matrix-multiplication) info, you will see this. I added it in two days ago.

The `"*"` is used for Hadamard product, i.e., the element-wise product. Since `tX` and `X` don't have the same dimension, you get error. (A hint: I don't know how you get `tX`. In R, function `t` transposes a matrix. See [transpose](/questions/tagged/transpose) info.)

---

I haven't used MATLAB for 10 years. The following docs for R2018a looks different from what I recall.

- [matrix-multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html);
- [element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html);
- [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)

Anyway, the syntax between two scientific languages are different enough.